# C++ array access optimization

Tags: c++, optimization

Im modding an open-source project(powder toy) and always compiling with /O2 (maximize speed) option, SSE2 code generation enabled and just inspected this:

```
void membwand(void * destv, void * srcv, size_t destsize, size_t srcsize)
{
    size_t i;
    unsigned char * dest = (unsigned char*)destv;
    unsigned char * src = (unsigned char*)srcv;
    for(i = 0; i < destsize; i++){
        dest[i] = dest[i] & src[i%srcsize];
    }
}
```

Here I replaced below lines

```
membwand(gravy, gravmask, size_dst, size_src);

membwand(gravx, gravmask, size_dst, size_src);

    // gravy, gravx and gravmask are 1MB each
```

with

```
membwand2(gravy,gravx, gravmask, size_dst, size_src);   
    // sizes are same, why not put all in a single function?
```

which is implemented as:

```
void membwand2(void * destv1, void * destv2,void * srcv, size_t destsize, size_t srcsize)
{
    if(destsize!=srcsize)
    {
        size_t i;
        unsigned char * dest1 = (unsigned char*)destv1;
        unsigned char * dest2 = (unsigned char*)destv2;
        unsigned char * src = (unsigned char*)srcv;
        for(i = 0; i < destsize; i++)
        {
            dest1[i] = dest1[i] & src[i%srcsize];
            dest2[i] = dest2[i] & src[i%srcsize];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        size_t i;
        unsigned char * dest1 = (unsigned char*)destv1;unsigned char * dest2 = (unsigned char*)destv2;
        unsigned char * src = (unsigned char*)srcv;
        unsigned char tmpChar0=0;unsigned char tmpChar1=0;unsigned char tmpChar2=0;
        unsigned char tmpChar3=0;unsigned char tmpChar4=0;unsigned char tmpChar5=0;
        unsigned char tmpChar6=0;unsigned char tmpChar7=0;unsigned char tmpChar8=0;
        unsigned char tmpChar9=0;unsigned char tmpChar10=0;unsigned char tmpChar11=0;
        unsigned char tmpChar12=0;unsigned char tmpChar13=0;unsigned char tmpChar14=0;
        unsigned char tmpChar15=0;unsigned char tmpChar16=0;unsigned char tmpChar17=0;
        unsigned char tmpChar18=0;unsigned char tmpChar19=0;unsigned char tmpChar20=0;
        unsigned char tmpChar21=0;unsigned char tmpChar22=0;unsigned char tmpChar23=0;
        unsigned char tmpChar24=0;unsigned char tmpChar25=0;unsigned char tmpChar26=0;
        unsigned char tmpChar27=0;unsigned char tmpChar28=0;unsigned char tmpChar29=0;
        unsigned char tmpChar30=0;unsigned char tmpChar31=0;
        for(i = 0; i < destsize; i+=32)
        {
            tmpChar0=src[i];tmpChar1=src[i+1];tmpChar2=src[i+2];tmpChar3=src[i+3];
            tmpChar4=src[i+4];tmpChar5=src[i+5];tmpChar6=src[i+6];tmpChar7=src[i+7];

            tmpChar8=src[i+8];tmpChar9=src[i+9];tmpChar10=src[i+10];tmpChar11=src[i+11];
            tmpChar12=src[i+12];tmpChar13=src[i+13];tmpChar14=src[i+14];tmpChar15=src[i+15];

            tmpChar16=src[i+16];tmpChar17=src[i+17];tmpChar18=src[i+18];tmpChar19=src[i+19];
            tmpChar20=src[i+20];tmpChar21=src[i+21];tmpChar22=src[i+22];tmpChar23=src[i+23];

            tmpChar24=src[i+24];tmpChar25=src[i+25];tmpChar26=src[i+26];tmpChar27=src[i+27];
            tmpChar28=src[i+28];tmpChar29=src[i+29];tmpChar30=src[i+30];tmpChar31=src[i+31];


            dest1[i] = dest1[i] & tmpChar0;
            dest1[i+1] = dest1[i+1] & tmpChar1;
            dest1[i+2] = dest1[i+2] & tmpChar2;
            dest1[i+3] = dest1[i+3] & tmpChar3;
            dest1[i+4] = dest1[i+4] & tmpChar4;
            dest1[i+5] = dest1[i+5] & tmpChar5;
            dest1[i+6] = dest1[i+6] & tmpChar6;
            dest1[i+7] = dest1[i+7] & tmpChar7;
            dest1[i+8] = dest1[i+8] & tmpChar8;
            dest1[i+9] = dest1[i+9] & tmpChar9;
            dest1[i+10] = dest1[i+10] & tmpChar10;
            dest1[i+11] = dest1[i+11] & tmpChar11;
            dest1[i+12] = dest1[i+12] & tmpChar12;
            dest1[i+13] = dest1[i+13] & tmpChar13;
            dest1[i+14] = dest1[i+14] & tmpChar14;
            dest1[i+15] = dest1[i+15] & tmpChar15;
            dest1[i+16] = dest1[i+16] & tmpChar16;
            dest1[i+17] = dest1[i+17] & tmpChar17;
            dest1[i+18] = dest1[i+18] & tmpChar18;
            dest1[i+19] = dest1[i+19] & tmpChar19;
            dest1[i+20] = dest1[i+20] & tmpChar20;
            dest1[i+21] = dest1[i+21] & tmpChar21;
            dest1[i+22] = dest1[i+22] & tmpChar22;
            dest1[i+23] = dest1[i+23] & tmpChar23;
            dest1[i+24] = dest1[i+24] & tmpChar24;
            dest1[i+25] = dest1[i+25] & tmpChar25;
            dest1[i+26] = dest1[i+26] & tmpChar26;
            dest1[i+27] = dest1[i+27] & tmpChar27;
            dest1[i+28] = dest1[i+28] & tmpChar28;
            dest1[i+29] = dest1[i+29] & tmpChar29;
            dest1[i+30] = dest1[i+30] & tmpChar30;
            dest1[i+31] = dest1[i+31] & tmpChar31;

            dest2[i] = dest2[i] & tmpChar0;
            dest2[i+1] = dest2[i+1] & tmpChar1;
            dest2[i+2] = dest2[i+2] & tmpChar2;
            dest2[i+3] = dest2[i+3] & tmpChar3;
            dest2[i+4] = dest2[i+4] & tmpChar4;
            dest2[i+5] = dest2[i+5] & tmpChar5;
            dest2[i+6] = dest2[i+6] & tmpChar6;
            dest2[i+7] = dest2[i+7] & tmpChar7;
            dest2[i+8] = dest2[i+8] & tmpChar8;
            dest2[i+9] = dest2[i+9] & tmpChar9;
            dest2[i+10] = dest2[i+10] & tmpChar10;
            dest2[i+11] = dest2[i+11] & tmpChar11;
            dest2[i+12] = dest2[i+12] & tmpChar12;
            dest2[i+13] = dest2[i+13] & tmpChar13;
            dest2[i+14] = dest2[i+14] & tmpChar14;
            dest2[i+15] = dest2[i+15] & tmpChar15;
            dest2[i+16] = dest2[i+16] & tmpChar16;
            dest2[i+17] = dest2[i+17] & tmpChar17;
            dest2[i+18] = dest2[i+18] & tmpChar18;
            dest2[i+19] = dest2[i+19] & tmpChar19;
            dest2[i+20] = dest2[i+20] & tmpChar20;
            dest2[i+21] = dest2[i+21] & tmpChar21;
            dest2[i+22] = dest2[i+22] & tmpChar22;
            dest2[i+23] = dest2[i+23] & tmpChar23;
            dest2[i+24] = dest2[i+24] & tmpChar24;
            dest2[i+25] = dest2[i+25] & tmpChar25;
            dest2[i+26] = dest2[i+26] & tmpChar26;
            dest2[i+27] = dest2[i+27] & tmpChar27;
            dest2[i+28] = dest2[i+28] & tmpChar28;
            dest2[i+29] = dest2[i+29] & tmpChar29;
            dest2[i+30] = dest2[i+30] & tmpChar30;
            dest2[i+31] = dest2[i+31] & tmpChar31;


        }
    }
}
```

Omp wall clock timings were **17ms** for two-lines version and **1.5ms** for one-line version. (after several thousand iterations)

**Question:** What could have cause the 9x speed-up? Data re-use of src[] or cache-utilization? Maybe code was not fit for vectorizing before, and unrolling enabled it, could it be the missing modulus operation for indexing? Should I add #pragma omp on top of loop?

**Edit:** #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4) made it worse somehow. Maybe just 1MB is not hiding multithread overhead?

**Edit2:** ommiting the modulus operator made it 2.5 ms but the performance increase from 2.5ms to 1.5ms (~%60 increase) must have come from unrolling/cache/...

Note: enabling "favor fast code", enabling whole program optimization, full optimization(/Ox)  and enabling intrinsics did not change the speed(maybe enabling SSE2 and /O2 was enough)

CPU: FX8150
IDE: Msvc

Comment: You can check auto vectorization with `/Qvec-report:1` or `/Qvec-report:2`.

Comment: Do these need to be in "extra compile options" string ?

Comment: You add it to the command line options

Comment: You are not comparing apples to apples.  To fairly compare the two functions the two line version should also have a branch when destsize==srcsize.

Comment: @Z boson : Okay, Im looking console output, it says thousands of "fail" messages, there are many functions here :O. Maybe I can find after half an hour. Why a compiler cannot optimize for destsize==srcsize branch? Do we need to wait for even wiser compilers?

Comment: use `/Qvec-report:1`  It only reports the ones that succeed.  But anyway I don't think that's the issue here.  It's more likely that you have a special case for the one line version when `destsize==srcsize` but not for the two line version

Comment: It showed _thiscall::GameSave::Transform(struct matrix2d,struct vector2d). A completely different function. Maybe some options made membwand2() not visible to /Qvec-report:1 ?

Comment: As an aside, if the data you are moving around is on the order to 1MB, why are you doing it char by char?  Surely casting to `int` would be a better choice (and dealing with the leftovers of course).  Or better still finding the largest natural data size for the platform.

Comment: What if the address/alignment of arrays are not sutable for ints to  make them vectorizable? Do I need an extra thing to add to array declarations?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Fair enough, but without knowing the structure  definition of the data you are moving its hard to tell.  But I expect that your compiler has already done its utmost to align the data for fastest possible access.  But if you are delving into micro optimizations then you should be considering that as well.

Comment: I hope you are comparing apple to apple, meaning the time it takes for  both function calls for membwand (....), compared to membwand2(...) because you need to check the time it takes to move the same amount of data

Comment: [OT] As `destsize` seems to be a multiple of `32`, if alignment allows it, you may work with `uint32_t` (or uint64_t) directly...

Comment: why isn't `tmpCharN` an array?  You fail to handle lengths which are not a multiple of 32 in the faster case.

Comment: Because making it array forces compiler to use stack. Other must be using sse registers (hopefully). Edit: I dont know any computers endianness so I did not want to make integers.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik You are doing a binary `and` and not caring what the value of the data is, so `endianness` should be irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) is the booster.You may google it for detailed info.

Of course modulus operation can be slow..You may test it by replacing

```
src[i%srcsize]
```

with

```
src[i]
```

for the sake of timing tests.

Comment: Just omitting modulus made it 2.5ms for wall timing. So the 2.5ms-1.5ms difference must have caused by unrolling and other things. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

there are several thing to consider here when comparing the two functions; from a high level perspective it looks as though the 2 line version should run faster than the 1 line version, however:

```
- the 1 line version has better instruction cache locatity
- the 1 line version puts less pressure on the registers( this is important 
 because if the compiler runs out of registers to use it may start using the 
 stack to move parameters around for the instructions it needs - which causes 
 an overhead)
```

As a optimization tip:

```
- you can try and use the "restrict"   keyword: **void membwand(void * _restrict_
destv, void *  _restrict_ srcv, size_t destsize, size_t srcsize);** This tells the
compiler that the two pointers are not aliasing - they are will never point at the
same memory location so the read/write instruction can be executed in the same cycle.
```

Comment: Tried _ _ restrict affter void * and it did not change performance. Maybe I need to use int rather than char?

Comment: no, data type has nothing to do with it; it's only a manner of passing extra info to the compiler